# When running PERCENTRANK I receive the "Unable to get the PercentRank property of the WorksheetFunction class" error

Tags: excel, vba, macros, percentile

I am trying to use the PERCENTRANK function to find what percentile the 'answer' ranks within column 'B'.  Starting at "Dim x As Double" is where the PercentRank function starts, I just included the rest of the code to show what else I am doing.

```
  Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Is This Item Catch Weight?", vbYesNo)
  If response = vbNo Then
    Dim cost, weight, answer As Variant
    Dim myrng As Range
        cost = InputBox("Please Enter PO Cost")
        weight = InputBox("Please Enter Net Weight")
        answer = cost / weight
        MsgBox "Price per KG is: " & answer
        Dim x As Double
            Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Set relevant_array = ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown))
            x = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(relevant_array.Address, answer)
            Debug.Print x
        Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is due to the fact that `PercentRank` works on an array / range, not an address.

Try changing that line to:

```
x = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(relevant_array, answer)
```

That should fix it.

Comment: @cam, Have you tried it in your spreadsheet directly? What are the values in `relevant_array` and for `answer`?